# Sequelize associations issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a issue in query, When we pass where condition in (include section) of find all.

My code is

```
db.Doctor.findAll({
    attributes : ['id','firstName','lastName',
                  'profilePicture','education','experience',
                  'fees','gender','mobile','email'],
    include: [
        { model : db.Category, attributes : ['title']},
        { model : db.Area, attributes : ['name']},
        { model : db.City, attributes : ['name']},
        { model : db.State, attributes : ['name']},
        { model : db.Country, attributes : ['name']},
        { model : db.DoctorClinicPicture, attributes : ['imagePath']},
        { 
            model : db.BookingFeedbackMaster, 
            attributes : ['rating','comment'],
            where : { status: 1 }
        }
    ],
    where : { id: req.query.doctorId},
    order: 'id ASC'
}).then(function(data){

    if (data != null )
    {
        res.json({status:true,msg:"Doctor viewed successfully!!",data:data});       
    }
    else
    {
        res.json({status:true,msg:"Doctor is temporary not available",data:""});        
    }

}).catch(function(err){
    res.json({status:"fail"});
});
```

It works well if any row present in BookingFeedbackMaster with the status 1 else it gives me no output.

I need to get the other data. No meter if i don't get the BookingFeedbackMaster data. if the condition not match.

Please help someone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the `BookingFeedbackMaster` with `required: false`. That way, you're performing a left outer join rather than inner join

Comment: yes it works thanks. Now I have to do make like query ie : Area start with 'abc' or city start with 'abc.' is there any way to do it ? so, I can use it in datatable jquery plugin.

Comment: Yes. For example to query name that starts with 'abc', use `name: { $like: 'abc%' }`

Comment: Actually, I have a search box and need to match it with all fields eg. firstname from Doctor table, title from Category table and so on. Please help me.